# Add and Remove List Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Im trying to make a calculator that can add and subtract values. At the same time, I wanted user to be able to add and remove list. My add and remove list button doesn't work. Can someone help me?

**here are my javascript code:**

```
var ViewModel = function() {
 var self = this;

self.value1 = ko.observable(0),
self.value2 = ko.observable(0),
self.mathOperator = ko.observableArray(['+', '-']);
self.selectedOperator = ko.observableArray(['+']);

self.calculateValues = ko.computed(function(){
    var selectedOperator = self.selectedOperator()[0],
        value1 = self.value1(),
        value2 = self.value2();

    switch(selectedOperator[0]){
        case '+': 
            return parseInt(value1) + parseInt(value2);
        case '-':
            return parseInt(value1) - parseInt(value2);
    }
});

self.addValue = funtion() {
    self.selectedOperator.push(self.selectedOperator()[0]);
}

self.removeValue = function(val) {
    self.selectedOperator.remove(val)
}
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

**and here are my html code:**

```
 <div id="MyCalc">
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: selectedOperator">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Value1</label>
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: value1" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <select data-bind="options: mathOperator, selectedOptions: selectedOperator,"></select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button data-bind="click: removeValue">Remove</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Value2</label>
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: value2" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <select data-bind="options: mathOperator, selectedOptions: selectedOperator,"></select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button data-bind="click: removeValue">Remove</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <button data-bind="click:addvalue">Add Another Value</button>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div id="result">Total:<span data-bind="text: calculateValues" />
</div>
```

or for easy viewing, this is the jdfiddle link. http://jsfiddle.net/sqkr65td/

Comment: There's too many issues with this code. Firstly you are using commas instead of semi-colons on these lines: `self.value1 = ko.observable(0), self.value2 = ko.observable(0),`. In `addValue` you spell `function` as `funtion`. Next, in your HTML, you are trying to do a loop over the operators: `foreach: selectedOperator`, which makes no sense. I guess you want to do a `foreach` over each row, which would consist of a value and an operator, but you have no observable array to hold this information. Here's a version that works slightly better: http://jsfiddle.net/sqkr65td/1/ but it still has issues

Comment: Saying that, commas do work, but I'd use semi-colons where you have them.

Comment: BTW asking multiple questions about the same thing at each stage of development is effectively asking us to write your code for you. Perhaps look at this instead: http://jsfiddle.net/Maslow/hsHt2/ and try to learn from what it does.